# Adding an action item to actionbar in fragment

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fragment

I am developing an app, and in that app have 3 activities

1. Login
2. Main
3. PhotoViewer extends fragmentActivity

in the manifest:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".PhotoViewerActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_photo_viewer"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.ceiva.snap.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

Can someone please advice me how to add "Customizer" text to the right of the actionbar for just the PhotoViewerActivity.

Also I tried doing this:

```
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
   // getActionBar().setIcon(android.R.color.transparent);
    getActionBar().setTitle("Back");
    Log.i(TAG, "actionbar  " + getActionBar().isShowing());

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    TextView customizerView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    customizerView.setEnabled(true);
    customizerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    customizerView.setText(getString(R.string.action_customizer));
    customizerView.setTextSize(16);
    customizerView.setPadding(100, 40, 40, 40);


    actionBar.setCustomView(customizerView);
```

the back title shows up on the left side but the textview doesnt show up.

Comment: are you talking about the menu option in your action bar/toolbar?

Comment: Yes, want to add another item to the action bar.

Comment: I created a new XML file with the required items in it as textview and did it as follows:

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setIcon(android.R.color.transparent);
        getActionBar().setTitle("Back");
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.picture_viewer_action_bar, null);
        getActionBar().setCustomView(v);

And it works as I intended.

Comment: You could have achieved this using using options menu.

Comment: I tried that but the menu item didnt show up. What your telling is to inflate a menu xml in onCreateOptionsMenu and access the menuitem there?

Comment: Yes, Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this

1.Create xml file in `menu` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:id="@+id/action_customize"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_customize"
      android:title="@string/action_customize"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

2.In your activity

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

3.You can set actions for your menu item with

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Take appropriate action for each action item click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_customize:
        // DO STUFF
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had previously used this, but doesnt work since my activity extends fragmentactivity and the setHasOptionsMenu(boolean) is not accessible.